# Set Values of List to ComboBox WP 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-phone

I have a generic List `myList<T>` and a ComboBox `cbx`.
How can I set one property (e.g. Firstname) of the List to the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the items of the list to the ComboBox as

```
foreach( var item in myList )
{
    comboBox.Items.Add( item.FirstName );
}
```

And if you want to select an item from within this updated comboBox. You can do that by

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1; // or whatever you want the index to be
```

You can also use other properties like selectedItem of comboBox control.